# How to use openocd to debug stm32h745-disco board?

Tags: stm32, openocd, stm32h7, st-link

I am using a dual core board stm32h745-disco, which contains cortex-m7 and cortex-m4.
When I used openocd to set up the gdb server for the board,

```
$ openocd -f tcl/board/stm32h745i-disco.cfg
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
Info : STLINK V3J10M3 (API v3) VID:PID 0483:374E
Info : Target voltage: 3.276064
Info : stm32h745xih6.cpu0: Cortex-M7 r1p1 processor detected
Info : stm32h745xih6.cpu0: target has 8 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for stm32h745xih6.cpu0 on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
```

I found that openocd only set up one gdb server for cortex-m7 core but neglect the cortex-m4 core.

Then I set a variable DUAL_CORE to 1 in the config file `stm32h745i-disco.cfg`.
However, it printed a warning and failed:

```
Warning : hla does not support multicore debugging
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
Info : STLINK V3J10M3 (API v3) VID:PID 0483:374E
Info : Target voltage: 3.277659
Error: init mode failed (unable to connect to the target)
```

The version information of my tools:

- openocd version: 0.11.0+dev-00454-gd3b71197b-dirty
- STLINKv3

I'm not familiar with openocd development or cortex-m debug features.
Is it possible for openocd to debug the cortex-m4 core of stm32h745-disco board?

Any comment is welcomed. Thank you in advance!